# Rearranging many columns with awk

Tags: awk, data-processing

I have a file with over 800 columns, and I want to perform some mild column rearrangement.  In particular, I need to drop a few columns, and make the last column the first column.

I programmatically generate a simple awk script to perform the rearrangement.  It looks like the following:

```
{ 
  print $820,$2,$3,$4, [lots more here, but skipping a few], $819
}
```

On one computer, this works just fine.  On another computer, it only works when I have a couple hundred columns selected, but for more columns, I get a core dump.  Is there any way to make this more portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing gawk fixed this problem... not sure what version of awk was being used previously.

Comment: Default awks:  Debian: mawk; RedHat and many others: gawk; Solaris: Close to original AT&T awk; AIX/HPUX: nawk line